# How to select a word after a # using preg_match in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to select a word that as hash using preg_match in php.

For Example consider this string:

> Facebook has re-designed #timeline and it is out in New Zealand

Now I want to select #timeline how to do that, I use this code but it select only #t

```
preg_match_all("/#[a-zA-Z0-9]/")
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's currently only set up to select a single character following the #.  Try this:

```
preg_match_all("/#[a-zA-Z0-9]+/")
```